# poisoned null-reference and short-circuit expression evaluation bug or UB?

Tags: c++, boost, undefined-behavior

I have come across a strange C++ crash recently after upgrading to gcc 7.2 which can be demonstrated using the following simple complete c++11 program:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>

struct MyObject
{
    static MyObject & null_obj()
        { return *static_cast<MyObject*>    (nullptr); }

    operator bool()
    {
        return value != 0;
    }

    int value = 0;
};

int foo(MyObject & obj = MyObject::null_obj())
{
    if (&obj != &MyObject::null_obj() && obj)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int result;

    if (argc == 1)
    {
        result = foo();
    }
    else
    {
        MyObject obj;
        obj.value = 1;

        result = foo(obj);
    }

    printf("%d", result);
}
```

The program can be built using: g++ -std=c++11 -O2

When executed with no arguments - program takes the top branch and crashes when built with gcc6.1 or later. When build with gcc 5.5 it does not crash.

When adding a dummy parameter - program takes second branch and does not crash as expected. The program also does not crash in any case when build without compiler optimizations.

The crash appear to happen when the conditional in foo() is evaluated.
Accordingly to short-circuit evaluation rules, the second condition in this code path should not be executed when first part of the expression is false.

When using a newer compiler, such as gcc 6.1 or later, assembler generated for foo looks like this:

```
foo(MyObject&):
  mov edx, DWORD PTR [rdi]
  xor eax, eax
  test edx, edx
  setne al
  ret
```

The crash culprit is the mov instructions at the top of the function.
The assembler for gcc 5.5 looks a bit different:

```
foo(MyObject&):
  test rdi, rdi
  je .L3
  mov edx, DWORD PTR [rdi]
  xor eax, eax
  test edx, edx
  setne al
  ret
.L3:
  xor eax, eax
  ret
```

The check on top of the function skips over the invalid read (as expected)

One can argue that using null reference in this manner is a fairly dodgy practice and I am tempted to agree even though I don't know exactly why. However I came across the same idiom in a boost::error_code class which uses boost::throws() : [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/system/doc/reference.html), [source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/boost/system/error_code.hpp).

I am aware that short-circuit eval does not apply to types that overload || and && operators but this is clearly not the case here.

Is this UB? (user error), compiler bug or something else?

**Update**:

My original reference to boost::error_code was for the version 1.65.1. This implementation was first introduced into boost version 1.40. I have since discovered that in latest version of boost the function was modified presumably to avoid the UB, but it is curious that it was permitted to stand unchallenged for so long. The new function uses non-zero integer constant:

```
namespace detail
{
    //  Misuse of the error_code object is turned into a noisy failure by
    //  poisoning the reference. This particular implementation doesn't
    //  produce warnings or errors from popular compilers, is very  efficient
    //  (as determined by inspecting generated code), and does not suffer
    //  from order of initialization problems. In practice, it also seems
    //  cause user function error handling implementation errors to be detected
    //  very early in the development cycle.
    inline system::error_code* throws()
    {
      // See github.com/boostorg/system/pull/12 by visigoth for why the return
      // is poisoned with (1) rather than (0). A test, test_throws_usage(), has
      // been added to error_code_test.cpp, and as visigoth mentioned it fails
      // on clang for release builds with a return of 0 but works fine with (1).
      return reinterpret_cast<system::error_code*>(1);
    }
}

inline system::error_code& throws() { return *detail::throws(); }
```

Comment: Dereferencing a null pointer is **undefined behavior**.  You can't set a reference to a dereferenced null. I *suspect* the older compiler after optimizations knows the input reference is being compared to a null, so generates the `test rdi, rdi` instruction, whereas the newer compiler knows the comparison is either bogus or optimized away completely so it doesn't generate the same `test`. Try changing `null_obj()` to return a reference to a real `MyObject` object and see how the compiler reacts

Comment: The valid object works as expected of course. I basically don't understand how boost is able to get away with this and they use  exactly the same code.

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/GxyklVeGAUaHPKRW Trust your compiler messages.

Comment: @rtz what line of the boost source? I don't see it. (No NULL, nullptr similar static_cast?)

Comment: just updated the broken links to latest boost source/docs

Comment: @rtz the broken link obviously didn't stop me. Do you have a line number?

Comment: In 1.65.1 they used this: inline system::error_code& throws()
    { return *detail::throws(); }
namespace detail { inline system::error_code * throws() { return 0; } } however it appears that in 1.66 this was changed to use 1 instead of zero. So my original comment applied to boost 1.65.1 but not 1.66

Comment: Cheers, it seems to me you answered your own questions :)

Comment: @rtz: Yep, looks like they had a bug then. No sign of it in the release notes but it's kind of small fry.

Comment: This code was unchanged in boost since version 1.40 which was released on Aug 2009. That's a pretty old bug! It does appear that it was changed very recently in 1.66

Comment: @rtz it wouldn't surprise me if it hadn't been a problem until recently. As things go with UB, the behaviour is ***undefined***: anything goes. If some compiler vendor started optimizing on the specific case, that would mean a new bug could manifest, triggering the bug fix.

Comment: To be fair that _is_ pretty shockingly poor code

Comment: Looking at it, it appears the **intent** of that code is to produce Undefined Behavior. The rewrite merely changes the flavor of UB.

Answer (score 3):

Well this is undefined behavior:

```
    { return *static_cast<MyObject*>    (nullptr); }
```

You are not allowed to convert a `nullptr` to a reference. It also breaks all the assumptions anybody that has a reference has.

Note: Undefined behavior means anything can happen (including a crash or not crashing).

Comment: I personally thought so, but the more I read about it the more I am confused. For example, see this debate: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232. Which seems to suggest that it is not so clear cut. I have not yet found a more recent standard quote which puts this to rest. If anybody find one please share here.

Comment: From: n4659 **11.3.2 References** Paragraph 5. `A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or
function. [ Note: In particular, a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only way
to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by indirection through a null pointer,
which causes undefined behavior. As described in 12.2.4, a reference cannot be bound directly to a bit-field.
— end note ]`

Answer (score 1):

Short-circuiting doesn't factor into it. You called `null_obj()`, a function that dereferences a null pointer. Your program consequently has undefined behaviour, period.

This rule isn't conditional on whether you tried to read some data from said broken value later.

If Boost does this, then Boost has a bug. Although it is unlikely that Boost does this.

Comment: If you have a separate question about Boost code, please do go ahead and ask it (providing evidence of your claim) but it is very unlikely that Boost dereferences a null pointer. Bugs do creep into any project, of course.

Comment: It could be argued that dereferencing nullptr isn't UB. But it is unquestionable that initializing a reference with the result of such an operation is UB.

Comment: @M.M: No, it cannot be argued that dereferencing nullptr isn't UB. The standard specifically states that it is. Furthermore, such an operation is meaningless. It does not matter what you attempt to do with the nonexistent value afterwards.